# How to troubleshoot custom code analysis assembly for SSDT

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, code-analysis

I am trying to implement a custom code analysis assembly for SSDT. I am following the guide at [Walkthrough Authoring a Custom Static Code Analysis Rule Assembly for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/walkthrough-author-custom-static-code-analysis-rule-assembly?view=sql-server-2017).

After I copy the resulting .dll and .pdb files to the designated directory, the project doesn't load, and I get this error message:

`One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly. Please see the Output Window for details.`

And there is this message in the Output window:

`Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`

I don't know how to troubleshoot this.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and an SSDT project that targets SQL Server 2016. So this is the directory I used as the target for the .dll and .pdb files:

`\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\150\Extensions`

This is the target directory given in the link:

`\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120\Extensions`

I've tried only copying the .dll file. I've tried restarting all running instances of Visual Studio as well as restarting the computer. I've tried running Visual Studio with the /log switch and looking for details in the ActivityLog.xml file.

Comment: Add a Debugger.Launch() as the first thing you do have f it isn’t hit then procmon to see if your dll is even being loaded

Comment: Yes, I can see it being loaded by the expected devenv.exe process in Process Explorer. Where would I put a Debugger.Launch() call? I don't see an obvious entry point in the assembly.

Comment: You have a class with this attribute: “LocalizedExportCodeAnalysisRule” add a static constructor to that and put it in there

Comment: Static constructor added and DLL rebuilt, but the error message still appears, and no debugger is launched.